# Pasting a table into a different excel instance

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that pastes a selected range from one instance of excel into a second instance of excel.

Right now I am facing 2 problems.

First problem is that I am not able to automatically paste the range on the same address as the select range (although on a different sheet).

Second problem is that I managed to paste values, but if I actually try to copy a table for instance, it gets pasted as a picture.

I am also not sure my code is very efficient, these are only bits and pieces I have copied from around the internet.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Workbook
Dim rng As Range, dst As Range
Dim vals() As Variant
Dim xlSht

Set ws = ThisWorkbook

'select second file
fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , Title:="Please select a file")
If fpath = False Then
 ' They pressed Cancel

    MsgBox "Stopping because you did not select a file"

    Exit Sub

Else

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fpath)
    xlApp.Visible = True

End If
ws.Sheets(2).Select


Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range",         Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

Set xlSht = xlApp.Sheets(1)

xlSht.Range("A1").Select

Set dst = xlApp.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range     
Select", Type:=8)




rng.Copy
dst.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

'vals = rng
'dst.Value = vals

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that excel cannot paste to another instance directly, instead it has to use the windows paste function. I think this is why your `PasteSpecial` pastes a picture of your range. If you use `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` it seems to work but a better way would be to open the second workbook in the same instance (eliminating xlApp):

```
'...
fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , Title:="Please select a file")
'...
Set xlBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath)

ws.activate  'wb might be a better name
set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

Set xlSht = xlBook.Sheets(1)
xlSht.Activate

set dst = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

rng.Copy
dst.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

If you want to paste to the same place as `rng` you could use

```
Set dst = xlSht.Cells(rng.Row,rng.Column)
```

But there might be a nicer way

Comment: Hi, the issue is that if I use xlpastevalues, all my formulas will be lost. is there an xlpastesomething, that keeps formulas as well?

Comment: Not for pasting to another instance of excel. Apparently `xlPasteFormulas` also pastes a picture. Did you try the method I recommended? When you open the second workbook in the same instance, the formulas will be copied.

Comment: The point is that the person I am doing this for wants to have the two seperate instances running (which doesnt make a lot of sense) because there are way too many formulas to keep the file in one instance.

Comment: Set dst = xlSht.Cells(rng.Row,rng.Column)
Also, this will only paste the first value of the range

Comment: I think you'd have to copy each cell contents individually to be safe if there is really no way of opening the other workbook in the same instance.  Pasting the whole range while only referring to the first cell of the destination works for me in the same instance.
What do you mean by that there are to many formulas to keep the file in one instance?

Comment: I don't really know as I haven't seen the actual file. Im just doing what was requested. Im going to mark your answer as correct as this was the way I ended up fixing the problem. Although will never know if it was actually possible to paste the formula.